# Modprobe mutiple instances of a kernel module to prevent race conditions (device tree)

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module, race-condition, device-tree

I am writing a kernel module for an embedded Linux system. The module works fine and is automatically loaded by using the `compatible` entry in the device tree. It creates a device in `/dev/`, which i can access using `ioctl` massages.

The module manages several discrete memory regions.

Since the device should be read and written by several programs at the same time, i am aware of the possibility of race conditions.

But there is **only one** program per memory region.

By loading the module several times, race conditions should not be any problem (and other difficulties are avoided too).

Q: Is it possible to load the **same** module several times (for each entry in the device tree)?

```
myDevs {
        compatible = "myDevs";
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;


        myown0@0xff000000 {
            compatible = "myown";
            name = "myown0";
            reg = <0xff000000 0x27>;
        };

        myown1@0xff002000 {
            compatible = "myown";
            name = "myown1";
            reg = <0xff002000 0x27>;
        };
};
```

Comment: Driver loads only once (->init) and the devices bound as many times as you want to (->probe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible to load same module twice.
Loading same module with different Major and Minor number is possible, instead of this you can handle this situation inside your driver.